# Laravel jetstream can't modify register blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

after i installed jetstream to my laravel project, i found that the auth folder is located in "vendor\laravel\jetstream\stubs\livewire\resources\views\auth" which was suppose to be located in "ressources\views" and i can't modify the blades to add more fields.What should i do ?
And thanks.

Comment: Read the official doc https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/features/authentication.html

Comment: @Espresso found it, Thank you very much ^^